# How to prevent JavaScript from running slow on minimized browser window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

I build an automation extension for chrome, what I noticed is that it's not really working when the browser window is minimized or in the background.

I read online
"JS doesn't stop running completely when windows are minimized. Instead, Chrome throttles their CPU usage, as well as making timers fire (from what i can tell), once per second as a max. It's not completely stopped, but becomes VERY slow."

which is pretty much what I'm experiencing, it doesn't stop completely but becomes very slow and inefficient.
Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

source: https://www.quora.com/Does-JavaScript-stop-running-in-minimized-browser-windows-in-Chrome

Comment: Browsers may allow the user to flip a switch to enable/disable timer throttling, but you can't do it programmatically.

Comment: Have you tried a WebWorker?,  The browser might still throttle if it needs to, but I've a feeling they will continue more than a hidden window..

Comment: @Keith not sure if a WebWorker will help me, the extension needs to do DOM manipulation.

Comment: You can still do DOM manipulation with a WebWorker, you just have to send messages.  Not tried this, but you might even find using a WebWorker with a Timer that sends a message to main thread might be all you need.  I'm sure I've seen some lib that actually did this to get around Timers pausing..  But if you do spin up a WebWorker, would be a shame not to use if for some heaving lifting too. :)

Comment: @Keith can't I just run it in the normal background script? Are WebWorkers really necessary?

Comment: Yes, as long as you keep the page in the foreground. But with that been the problem your trying to solve I think webWorkers are currently your best option.   This link might help -> https://hackwild.com/article/web-worker-timers/

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

> Most browsers stop sending requestAnimationFrame() callbacks to
> background tabs or hidden s to improve performance and battery
> life. Timers like setTimeout() slow down on background/inactive tabs
> to help improve performance.

But there are a few different exceptions or deals that you might be able to take advantage of:

> Some processes are exempt from this behavior. In these cases, you can
> use the Page Visibility API to reduce the performance impact of tabs
> while they are hidden.
>
> Tabs that are playing audio are considered foreground and are not
> slowed down. Tabs running code that uses real-time network connections
> (WebSockets and WebRTC) are not slowed down to prevent these
> connections from being closed unexpectedly. IndexedDB processes are
> also not throttled to avoid timeouts.

Maybe you could have one of these processes run to keep the tab active, how about a nice song when the window is minimized ;) hehe